# While previewing the Cloudflare app previously stored cookies are coming into play

Tags: cloudflare-apps

Scenario:

- Let's say I'm setting a cookie (name=John Doe;path=/).
- After some time I'm again setting a cookie (name=Jonny;path=/).
- Now, If I get the cookie **name** I'm receiving "John Doe".

May I know Why I'm not receiving the latest value? Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting this cookie in a Cloudflare app and then seeing the old cookie stored in the app previewer? or is the old cookie stored incorrectly on a site with it installed? 
If it's on only the previewer, this is likely something to do with the iframe.

Comment: The issue is happening while previewing only.

Comment: Does this still happen when you open the previewer in a new tab?

Comment: Yes. If I open previewer in a new tab or click on the "GO" button, I'm having two cookies "name=Jonny;name=Jonny;". This time two cookies have same value. First cookie is older cookie and Second one is the current cookie.